# Rails Acts as Votable check to see if user logs in to vote

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

I'm getting errors when I log out:

```
undefined method `voted_for?' for nil:NilClass
```

This is my view:

```
- unless (current_user.voted_for? @project) && (@project.liked_by current_user)
  = link_to like_project_path(@project), method: :put, class: "btn btn-default" do
    %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-heart
      = pluralize(@project.get_likes.size, 'like')
- else 
  = link_to unvote_project_path(@project), method: :put, class: "btn btn-default" do
    %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-heart
      = pluralize(@project.get_likes.size, 'like')
```

If I remove `current_user.voted_for? @project` and just leave `@project.liked_by current_user` then for some reason, it'll automatically like the project when I refresh the page. Even if I clear my database, it'll add a like to it when I go into the project.

So when I try to log out, I get that error, but when I'm logged in, there is no error and it seems to be functioning correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`current_user` is not defined in your view, it is defined in the controller.  You should be putting all your logic in your controller

In your controller:

```
@instance_variable = (current_user.voted_for? @project) && (@project.liked_by current_user)
```

Then in your view:

```
unless @instance_variable
```

Answer (score 0):

That's odd, but I don't know the particular gem that you're using.  Perhaps you should also check that `current_user` isn't `nil`?

Something like: `if current_user && current_user.voted_for?(@project)` ...

Side note: stylistically, it's best to avoid `unless` .. `else` since it's hard to read.